# Drupal Custom Node Access

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I need some complex node access in Drupal and I have decided to role my own module. What hooks do I need to look at to allow access to nodes. Do you have any examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something of a pain in Drupal 6 - `hook_access` can only tweak access on node types created by the module it's part of, and `hook_node_access` is new in Drupal 7.

Unfortunately, the best solution I've found for this is via a core patch that adds an `access` op to `hook_nodeapi`. Details can be found [here](http://www.johnandcailin.com/blog/cailin/implementing-hookaccess-cck-content-types).

Comment: Not a fan of patching core. Going to have to do some major thinking.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not a fan of doing that either. D7 finally fixes this **glaring** omission.

Comment: It may not be best practice but could I use hook_view and return something else if they don't meet my conditions?

Comment: hook_nodeapi() is what I need

Comment: @ceejayoz: You really don't need to patch core, see my example. I believe that is how many of the node access modules work in D6.

Answer (score 5):

All you need is [hook_access](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--node.php/function/hook_access/6)

If you want to do access control on all nodes, this can be done with a bit of tweaking. You can use `hook_menu_alter` to add your custom access control function to 'node/%node'. It could look like this:

```
function module_menu_alter($items) {
  $items['node/%node']['access callback'] = 'module_node_access';
}

function module_node_access($op, $node) {
  if ($special_case) {
    return FALSE;
  }
  elseif ($special_case_2) {
    return TRUE;
  }
  // Default, let Drupal handle it.
  return return node_access($op, $node);
}
```

Comment: Nope. "This hook allows node modules to limit access to the node types they define." If you're trying to tweak access to, say, a CCK node type, `hook_access` won't work in your custom module, as your custom module didn't define the node type.

Comment: Yeah, I spent a day trying to get that to work until I stumbled across an explanation of why it doesn't work. You'd think that'd be more prominently explained in that documentation page...

Comment: @will, Updated with details on how to roll out your own access module for all nodes.

Comment: Interesting approach to it. I'll have to give that a shot.